# Define template strings as const to evaluate later

Tags: javascript, templates, template-literals

Is there a way to accomplish something like this:

```js
const API_URL = `https://api.my-data-provider.com/items/${id}`

// [...]

// and later on or in another file, use it with something like
const result = await fetch(API_URL(id)) // or API_URL.apply(id), API_URL.apply({ id: 23}), etc...
```

I want to save template literals in a constants / configuration file, to use them later

Or is there any other standard or well established way to do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a function for this:

```
const generateApiUrl = (id) => `https://api.my-data-provider.com/items/${id}`;
const result = await fetch(generateApiUrl(id))
```

Comment: Yeah, I like it, it can't get any easier that this...