# How To Import JS Code and Evaluate in Importing JS file

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

Uning just ES6/Modules...

I am trying to import a js file that has an object of content with variables that are referenced in the importing js file. I am getting *Uncaught ReferenceError: params is not defined*.  Assuming bc js is trying to evaluate the var in the js object file when I need to have it do it once it uses it as a reference.  Is this possible... I've done similar things for translations in Angular projects, but this is pure js only.

Js Importer Example:

```
import { appText } from "../../content.js";

export class Item {
  message;

  init(params) {
    this.message.innerHTML = appText.item.message;
  }
```

Content object js

```
export const appText = {
  item: {
    message: `You're ${params.firstName} ${params.lastName}.`
  }
}
```

Comment: Template literals are evaluated immediately when encountered. So you cannot import them and expect the evaluation to happen later. You can delay their evaluation if you use them in a function but the function should still have parameter(s) to match the substitutions in the template. [Define template strings as const to evaluate later](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66496227) All JS code is lexically scoped, importing script A into script B, doesn't evaluate A within B's scope.

Comment: @VLAZ is there a way to pass it all as a string and then evaluate it as a temp lit?

Comment: This works: eval('`' +appText.item.message+ '`'), when passing it as a string.  Is this really dangerous and does it cause a lot of overhead if I am eval-ing like 40 items?

Comment: Yes, it's dangerous if you don't have control over `appText.item.message`. It's really best to define a function and call it.

Comment: Yeah, I do have control over it, but I think I'll go this route - this.message.innerHTML = appText.item.message(params);  message: (params) => `You're ${params.firstName} ${params.lastName}.`

Answer (score 0):

Two ways I found/think you could do it...

1. As a function, `this.message.innerHTML = appText.item.message(params);` `message: (params) => You're ${params.firstName} ${params.lastName}`.
2. eval, be that the file is controlled and not user input
   -- `this.message.innerHTML = eval('' +appText.item.message+ '')` and as a plain string `message: 'Are you sure you want to remove<br><strong><u>${params.firstName} ${params.lastName}</u></strong>` from this group?'

I would have hoped to find a better answer, but seems not.